# Proceso de Obtencion access_token de BBVA API

Tags: api, postman

Estoy intentando consumir la API de BBVA atraves de Postman, sin embargo estoy teniendo problemas al obtener el token de mi aplicacion, el proceso que estoy siguiendo es el que se detalla en la siguiente guia:

> Documentación BBVA.

[Documentacion BBVA](https://www.bbvaapimarket.com/es/api-developers/llamadas-api/#article-autenticacion-de-tres-patas)

En la guia se especifica que para hacer una llamada a una API con autenticación de dos patas, primero hay que obtener un access_token y posteriormente se hace la llamada a la API con el access_token obtenido.

Previamente cree una cuenta y una aplicacion para consultas del api "Cuentas de particulares
Mx_LoansAuto_Sbx" (la que se especifica en la guia) esto con el fin de aprendizaje.

> API

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Mi petición por postman.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que esta solicitud deberia retornar un json como este :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para obtener el valor del campo CREDENCIALES debemos convertir a base64 ([www.base64encode.org](http://www.base64encode.org)) la concatenación de: appID, “:” y Secret OAuth, es decir: appID:Secret_OAuth. Sin embargo este valor ya lo da automaticamente la aplicacion de BBVA

Lo valide y si es el mismo utilizando el encriptado base64

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo el error a la llamada es 401:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan apoyar a solucionar

Muchas gracias

Saludos

Comment: Hola Alejandro, los códigos y mensajes de error, deben estar como texto, no en imágenes, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta para adecuarla a las normas del
 sitio a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos,